# Can numpy.linalg.inv compute the inverse of a complex-valued matrix?

Tags: numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, complex-numbers, inverse

Can numpy.linalg.inv compute the inverse of a **complex-valued** matrix?
There seems very little information about this question with google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
In [190]: np.array([[1.2+3j,0],[0,2+3j]])
Out[190]: 
array([[1.2+3.j, 0. +0.j],
       [0. +0.j, 2. +3.j]])
In [191]: np.linalg.inv(_)
Out[191]: 
array([[0.11494253-0.28735632j, 0.        +0.j        ],
       [0.        +0.j        , 0.15384615-0.23076923j]])
```

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask one more question: is the accuracy and precision the same as the computation with the real valued matrix?